# How do I check if the program cout is empty?

Tags: c++, recursion, iostream, cout

I am facing a problem where I have a void function which prints out AVL tree node values using inorder traversal. However, I also need to print out "EMPTY" if the void function does not have any cout. 
 And since the void function is recursive so I assume the `cout << "EMPTY" << endl;` can not be inside the function (Actually I tried but a lot of unncessary EMPTY were produced).
My question is that is there any way I can check the program/function cout, something like: if(cout is empty){ print "EMPTY" }

```
void inorder(node* n){
    if(n != NULL){
        inorder(n->left);
        cout << n->value << ' ';
        inorder(n->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you should add a return value to the function and use that to decide what to do.

Comment: We need to see where you first call `inorder` because that's where you need to output `EMPTY` if the output is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query `cout` to find out whether it printed something or not.  There actually is a method ([tellp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp)) that returns the position of a [std::basic_ostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) stream (which is what `cout` is), but when called on `cout` is always  returns -1, presumably because `cout` is not keeping track of the number of characters it has printed (aka its "position" within the output stream).

Therefore the only practical way to know if something was printed is to instrument your `inorder()` function to provide that information to the caller, via a return-value (as Retired Ninja suggests in the comments) or via some other mechanism (e.g. writing to a by-reference argument, or setting a global variable, or etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `inorder`, it is guaranteed to produce some ouput if, and only if, its parameter is not `NULL`. So you can do this:

```
 void inorderTraverse(node* n)
 {
     if (n == NULL)
         std::cout << "EMPTY" << std::endl;
     else
         inorder(n);
 }
```

Then, wherever you first call `inorder`, call `inorderTraverse` instead.

Comment: This will print “EMPTY” for all subtrees.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I don't understand what you mean. The code that prints `EMPTY` cannot ever invoke on a sub-tree since it's not part of the `inorder` function.

Comment: Oop, you’re right, sorry I misread your code. Your solution is essentially the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to have *two* functions:

- one that the user calls, and which will print “EMPTY” if the tree is empty
- one that does everything else

The common way to do this is with a “detail” namespace, but any other method for having a helper function would work as well:

```
namespace detail{
    void inorder(node* n){
        if(n != NULL){
            inorder(n->left);
            std::cout << n->value << ' ';
            inorder(n->right);
        }
    }
}

void inorder(node* n){
    if(n) detail::inorder(n);
    else std::cout << "EMPTY";
}
```

Another common way of doing this is having an additional, defaulted-argument (boolean, in this case) to indicate whether or not it is a toplevel invocation:

```
void inorder(node* n, bool is_top=true){
    if (n != NULL){
        inorder(n->left, false);
        std::cout << n->value << ' ';
        inorder(n->right, false);
    }else if(is_top){
        std::cout << "EMPTY";
    }
}
```

I personally do not like flaggy code, though — the helper function is an old, recognizable idiom and avoids the overhead of the boolean tests at every leaf node.